# Complementing image to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to create a background image that has two images, but I can’t complement the second image to the right.

I can’t manage to make it look like one whole picture, but in one place.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.home-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-content {
  background: url(../img/leftwing.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  left: 0;
}

.right-content {
  background: url(../img/rightwing.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-wrapper">
  <div class="left-content">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    a
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason I didn’t make it a whole background is these two have a different function when you hover over them.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is what I have instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by adding background position in your css. Try this code.

```
.left-content{
    background: url(../img/leftwing.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    left: 0;
}
.right-content{
    background: url(../img/rightwing.png);
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-position` to both `.right-content` and `.left-content`

```
.right-content {
  background-position: left center;
  width: 50%; /* << this was 100%, typo? */
}
.left-content {
  background-position: right center;
}
```